# WebMatrix 2 asp pages issues

Tags: asp.net, html, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

When I open my web site in WebMatrix 2 to update the database and add some pages,  I get errors in my asp pages like:

This document type is not supported. IntelliSense and validation for this document type will be based on HTML 5.

The problem is with the HTML tags !!

Any one can help please...

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using a version that does not have "intellisense" for HTML 5, happens with Visual Studio 2010 without SP1, try to update it or just ignore the warnings if they do not bring problems.